# How does xrandr identify/choose which resolutions to offer?

Tags: xorg, xrandr

My monitor has a maximum resolution of 2560x1440 (16:9). On one machine I run, (VMWare VM), xrandr identifies the highest resolution as 2560x1600 (16:10), and no other resolution suggested by xrandr is 16:9 either.

I'm trying to track down the source of this, so I get it fixed. So what layers below xrandr affect the reported resolutions?

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0 +   60.3  (1.33)
   2560x1600      60.0  (1.6)
   1920x1440      60.0  (1.33)
   1856x1392      60.0  (1.33)
   1792x1344      60.0  (1.33)
   1920x1200      59.9  (1.6)
   1600x1200      60.0  (1.33)
   1680x1050      60.0* (1.6)
   1400x1050      60.0  (1.33)
   1280x1024      60.0  (1.25)
   1440x900       59.9  (1.6)
   1280x960       60.0  (1.33)
   1360x768       60.0  (1.77)
   1280x800       59.8  (1.6)
   1152x864       75.0  (1.33)
   1280x768       59.9  (1.66)
   1024x768       60.0  (1.33)
   640x480        59.9  (1.33)
```

Cut out all the "VirtualX disconnected" lines following the above info. I also took the liberty of calculating and adding the aspect ratio for each of the resolutions within parenthesis, so that's not my xrandr being special and outputing that.

Comment: Could you post the output of `xrandr -q` ?

Comment: @maurelio79 Done

Comment: The ArchLinux wiki discusses this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr